# Move locked file

Tags: c#

I'm trying to move (File.Move) locked .dll file to perform application update. File.Move method was executed without exceptions. But file was not moved. I mean after executing File.Move method I have two copies of the same file: in destination folder and in source folder. Here is the code  :)

```
File.Move(fileName, newFileName);
```

Could someone explain the reason of this?

Comment: If file is in use you can't delete it (OS prevents this)... do you expect a different behaviour?

Comment: Edited. OS can move locked files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

File.Move across volumes performs two operations in sequence:

1. File Copy
2. File Delete

It seems as though the first succeeds and the second silently fails. Results as expected.

Note from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx

> If you try to move a file across disk volumes and that file is in use, the file is copied to the destination but not deleted from the source.

Comment: Some remark to answer: File.Move performs Copy and Delete only when we are trying to move file across volumes. Else File.Move just updates file metadata (because of it is possible to move locked files).

Comment: Well is this being moved across volumes? Would explain it all.

Comment: I was totally unaware of being able to move a locked file without any exceptions. But I can confirm that it is possible. 

I had a .NET 6 `PublishAsSingleFile` console app that did this by accident, and I got DLL load errors (`FileNotFoundException`) in my logging after move, as they were loaded on demand from (what it thinks is) the main module directory. But moving that single EXE also moved all DLL's because of how it was published (single file). Unfortunately I could not find any source that supports this behavior except for the comment from @MaratFaskhiev

Answer (score 0):

Normally in this case, you either have a separate update process that doesnt require any of the apps DLLs so you spawn the updater, which can move everything it likes, does the update, and restart the app.

Or, like an installer, you submit the change of file to occurr on next reboot.

Answer (score 0):

`File.Move` method will first copy the file `fileName` to the file '`newFileName`'. Once the first step is successful it will delete the file '`fileName`'.

Now if the file '`fileName`' is already open/locked it will not be able to delete the file.